# Calculating probability of values for multiple dice rolls where sum is equal or greater than 4

Tags: probability, dice

Assuming we have 6 sided dice and play game of rolling dice each turn until we get sum value of at least 4.

For example we know that game will always finish with value less or equal than 9 because on 1. turn max value we can get without finishing the game is 3, then we can get highest value  of 6, all values on 2. turn will result in finishing game.

My question is, what is the probability that game will finish with value 5, 6 or 7?

What's the correct approach to solve this probabilities? My difficulty is that each next turn is conditional on probability of previous turns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that the final sum will be in the range of $4$ through $9$. Determine all possible rolls that yield the final result. Add up the probabilities as each event will be disjoint.

Example: to get to 4, you have the following roll patterns:

$$4 \\ 3, 1 \\ 2, 2 \\ 2, 1, 1 \\ 1, 3\\ 1,2,1 \\1, 1, 2 \\ 1, 1, 1, 1$$

This gives:

$$P(4) = P(5) = P(6) = \dfrac{1}{6}+3\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^2}+3\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^3}+\dfrac{1}{6^4} = \dfrac{344}{1296} \\ P(7) = 3\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^2}+3\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^3}+\dfrac{1}{6^4} = \dfrac{127}{1296} \\ P(8) = 2\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^2}+3\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^3}+\dfrac{1}{6^4}=\dfrac{91}{1296} \\ P(9) = \dfrac{1}{6^2}+2\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^3}+\dfrac{1}{6^4}=\dfrac{49}{1296}$$

As a semi-verification, let's add it all up to make sure it adds to $1$:

$$\dfrac{3\cdot 343+127+91+49}{1296} = 1$$

This appears to be the correct probability for each result.

Another way to think about this: Let's consider the game in rounds. It can end on round $1$ with a roll of $4,5,6$. So that is a $\dfrac{1}{6}$ probability for each.

It can end on round $2$ with a first roll of $1,2,3$ for round $1$ to reach any of $4,5,6,7$ (so $3\dfrac{1}{6^2}$ probability of each), a first round roll of $2,3$ can reach $8$ for a probability of $2\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^2}$, or $3$ can reach $9$ for a probability of $\dfrac{1}{6^2}$.

It can end on round $3$ with the first two rolls as $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)$ and reach $4,5,6,7,8$ for a probability of $3\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^3}$. And the first two rolls being $(1,2),(2,1)$ can reach $9$ with probability $2\cdot \dfrac{1}{6^3}$.

And it can reach any result on the fourth round by rolling three consecutive $1$'s followed by any roll of the $d6$ for a probability of $\dfrac{1}{6^4}$ each.

Comment: Ok, so solution you propose is to calculate all possibilities for values 4,5,6,7,8,9, then for example you showed that for values 4 there are 8 possibilities so to get probability of game finishing with sum value 4 we divide 8 with number of all possibilities of values 4,5,6,7,8,9?

Comment: @peterparada no, these outcomes are not equally probable. Getting a specific outcome on one die roll has probability $\dfrac{1}{6}$ while getting a specific outcome with four die rolls has probability $\dfrac{1}{6^4}$. And you need to be careful with the outcome enumeration that you find all possible outcomes that yield a result and include no impossible outcomes. For example: for 5, $$5\\ 3,2\\2,3\\2,1,2\\1,4\\1,2,2\\1,1,3\\1,1,1,2$$ are the only possible outcomes. You may be thinking "where is $4,1$?" But that possibility yields a sum of $4$.

Comment: Yes I know probability of 9 is different than for example probability of ending game with sum of 4. We are on the same page here I think, but to calculate probability value (not just number of possible occurences), I need to divide it with all possible occurences therefore divide with all possible occurences, i.e. sum of all occurences for games with ending sum of 4,5,6,7,8,9. Ok that makes sense just thought there is more elegant answer.

Comment: @peterparada you should not divide by the total number of possible occurrences. You only do that when all outcomes are equally probable. It is more likely that you will roll a $4$ with one die than you will roll a $1$ then a $3$. They are not equally probable events. So, you should not divide by the total number of outcomes.

Comment: Yeah, actually figured it out by "playing" game 1 million times (in javascript code), and can infer from it pretty accurate probability (4,5,6 - 26.5%, 7 - 9.8%, 8 - 7%, 9 - 3.8%), also tried to do it naively by calculating probability of each step - for example there is 1/2 probability game will finish on 1st attempt and 1/2 probability it will finish on rest of turns, I assume probability of 4,5,6 is same but to get sum of 7,8,9 is less probable, but what is right process of calculation these sum probabilities?

Comment: @peterparada I updated my answer

Comment: That's more clear to me now. Thanks!